# Load* POCO references using OrmLite and SQL

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a few questions about ServiceStack.OrmLite's POCO reference capabilities.

1. When using the `Load*()` API to fetch POCO with references, does it internally generate & run a single SQL query (with appropriate JOINs) to return the POCO and its references, or does it run separate queries (one for POCO, then one for each reference)?
2. Is there a way to make the `Load*()` API accept a custom SQL query (instead of an SqlExpression), and still be able to automatically load the references, rather than have to call `LoadReferences()` for each object?

I'm trying to specify a custom SQL statement and return a list of POCO with references pre-loaded, hopefully running a single query under the hood.

Hoping for someone to chime in with some insight.

Answer (score 3):

Load References loads **1 query** to load the main table and **1 query** to load the child references irrespective of how many rows the child references has.

You can see the SQL generated by looking at the SQL Generated that's being logged to the Console output when you using a `ConsoleLogFactory`. For example here's a `LoadSelect` [example you can run on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=ed29fb09e39b7dde423f18f1471eadf7&collection=cd381848f252be2a84f8c239ed0d241b) with its Console Output:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

public class Track
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

var oldestTracks = db.Select(db.From<Track>()
    .Where(x => Sql.In(x.Year, db.From<Track>().Select(y => Sql.Min(y.Year)))));
"Oldest Tracks: {0}".Print(oldestTracks.Dump());

var oldestTrackIds = oldestTracks.Map(x => x.Id);
var earliestArtistsWithRefs = db.LoadSelect(db.From<Artist>()
    .Where(a => oldestTracks.Map(t => t.ArtistId).Contains(a.Id)));
"Earliest Artists: {0}".Print(earliestArtistsWithRefs.Dump());
```

Console Output:

```
DEBUG: SQL: SELECT "Id", "Name" 
FROM "Artist"
WHERE "Id" In (@0,@1)
PARAMS: @0=3, @1=4
DEBUG: SQL: SELECT "Id", "Name", "ArtistId", "Album", "Year" FROM "Track" WHERE "ArtistId" IN (SELECT "Artist"."Id" 
FROM "Artist"
WHERE "Id" In (@0,@1))
PARAMS: @0=3, @1=4
Earliest Artists: [
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: Nirvana,
        Tracks: 
        [
            {
                Id: 5,
                Name: Smells Like Teen Spirit,
                ArtistId: 3,
                Album: Nevermind,
                Year: 1991
            },
            {
                Id: 6,
                Name: Heart-Shaped Box,
                ArtistId: 3,
                Album: In Utero,
                Year: 1993
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 4,
        Name: Pearl Jam,
        Tracks: 
        [
            {
                Id: 7,
                Name: Alive,
                ArtistId: 4,
                Album: Ten,
                Year: 1991
            },
            {
                Id: 8,
                Name: Daughter,
                ArtistId: 4,
                Album: Vs,
                Year: 1993
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Where you can see 2 queries, 1 query to load the main table and 1 query to load the Tracks child references.

Comment: Thanks @mythz. The main table query is complex and resource-intensive, so I ended up executing it with the `Select` API, then executing a separate query on the reference table for unique Ids from the main query, and finally merging both resultsets. It's faster and more optimum in my case, than a `LoadSelect`, which re-runs the main query as a reference query. I guess one caveat to this approach is that the number of unique Ids from the main query must be reasonable, so as to not go past the parameter limit for `IN` clause.